# Pop to another page with data

Tags: flutter, navigator

I want to send boolean to my other page when i pop from specific screen let's call it Screen2
and my main screen is Screen1,

**Screen3**

```
bool data=true;
   
 Navigator.of(
   context,
  ).popUntil((_) => count++ >= 2);
```

**Screen2**

User will push from first Screen1 to Screen2 then Screen2 to Screen3 then pop back from Screen3 to Screen1

**Screen1**

```
  bool isScreen1PoppedFromScreen2(data){
    if(data)
      return true;
    else{
    return false;
    }
}
```

is there anyway to do it without using Navigator.push, or Navigator.pushNamed ?

Answer (score 1):

While popping from your second screen you can

```
Navigator.pop(context, true);
```

And in first screen you can navigate to 2nd one like

```
final result =Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),);
```

now you can use the 'result' as boolean variable to check whether navigated or not.(When you will pop the second screen then the value of result will become true i.e you have popped the second screen)

Comment: actually there are 3 screen, im pushing first to second, and second to third, then popping third to first, going to edit question.